# How to show messageBox/ alert in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

How can i show a messageBox in my asp.net page? (i write with c#)
whice lines i need to write?

Comment: Wow, at least [78 similar questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=asp.net+messagebox).

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "test", "<script>alert('hi');</script>");
 }
```

Comment: I found this more interesting. https://www.telerik.com/blogs/executing-javascript-function-from-server-side-code (I use scriptmanager, I tried this and it works :)

Answer (score 1):

in ASP.NET there is no direct control like in winforms for Message Boxes.
You can download the ASP.NET toolkit and use the ModalPopupExtender and then create your own MessageBox.

Or.. You can use javascript in your ASP.NET page to show an Alert using Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use JavaScript to do this, by  using `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` or `RegisterClientScriptBlock` to call the client-side `alert("this is my messagebox");` JS method.

You can also use AJAX control toolkit ModalPopupExtender, or JQuery's dialog component.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript

```
Button1.Attributes.Add("onclick","alert('Hello World!!!');");
```

Answer (score 0):

write the following on the event of your choosing:

```
Interaction.MsgBox("Your Text Goes Here");
```